# Reusing attributes - Composition over inheritance

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, uml

From head first design patters (on decorator pattern):

"That is exactly right. If you have
code that relies on the concrete component’s
type, decorators will break that code.
As long as you only write code against
the abstract component type, the use of
decorators will remain transparent to your
code. However, once you start writing code
against concrete components, you’ll want to
rethink your application design and your use
of decorators."

Well, i came along with this problem, i do want to apply inheritance because i have to reuse metods and attributes, but i still need to work based on class/type. Using composition over inheritance works well for methods, but how can i achive the same thing on attributes? I can't make a composition out of that... or do i?

PD: Thanks for your time and, hopefully, you can get accross with my english :P

### Edit1

My problem:

- I have Admins, supervisors, technicals and consultants. the administrator is responsible for a set of supervisors, technicals and consultants.
- Administrator could use supervisors to cover technical functions.
- Employees have a main role.
- Technicals could be consultants aswell.
- If a technical perform consultant task, will be paid a bonus.
- Consultants works on client's offices whereas admins, supervisors and technicals works in company's offices.
- A employee working off-company is asigned with a cellphone number, while and employee working on-company can be called to office's intern.
- Employee number, name and salary is the information that is know about employees.

Asume them all a set of methods worth to inherit. (Asured methods, some to know where is an employee working, and another that tells the phone number to contact him).
So, at first i inherited them all from a class Employee, but that leads admin with a reference to Employee to know the set of employees he have on charge, thus, im not able to retribe his set of employees and schedule them work based on their role type.

I cant help but thinkin i'm breaking liskov principle... But inheritance seems so convenient, attributes, above all.

Comment: I suggest you break this up into several questions.

Comment: Some code examples would help, it is complex to understand the question without the code and without the details about your concrete case. In general in terms of OOP you should not "reuse attributes" at all, attributes are data which should be encapsulated inside classes and stay private.

Comment: First, convenience is the death of design :). The real question is, are all those roles "really" employees? If yes, then there is nothing wrong with inheritance. Then you could extend Employee with isTaskAcceptable(Task), accept(Task), or similar. Then you don't have to watch for type, because all employee objects can decide themselves what tasks they are able to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer without knowing the whole context. However, based on my experience, inheritance in such situation (user + role) sooner or later will lead you to a problems.

IMHO admins, supervisors, technicals and consultants are all employees, but this doesn't mean we should end with Admin, Supervisor, etc. class that extends Employee. I think all of them are Employee, but their Role is different. If Relationship between Employee and Role would be well organized we can have an Employee with multiple Roles:

```
class Employee {}
interface Role {}
class Admin implements Role {}
class Superviosr implements Role {}
```

Class object should hold all attributes and behavior that is common for all employees and Role/Roles should determine the behavior specific for particular Role.

Probably the more harder part would be to come up with a good solution for the problem with admin and its reference to the other employees. Yet, it would require more information on how it is used in code/application.